# Facebook PHP SDK echo current user's networks

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

How would I go about determining a user's networks so that I have them in a format that can be inserted into a database? I understand that I have to make an FQL request for affiliations but after that I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `affiliations` field of the `user` table within the FQL (see here > http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user)

> **affiliations**
>   *array* 
>   The networks to which the user being queried
>   belongs. The status field within this field will only return results
>   in English